# Is there anyway I can run colab notebook from my local computer?

Tags: python, django, google-colaboratory

I am writing my Django web application locally using VScode but as part of my work is done using deep learning to create 3D reconstruction for the face and can not be done locally because I need powerful gpu. What I am trying to do is connect a function to use this notebook... so can anyone tell me if It's applicable?

Comment: so you want to run Django on local computer and calculations on server with GPU? Maybe you should run it as two separated services (web pages) and send information using HTTP/HTML/JSON. But if you need to send many information then it could be better to run all on Google server.

Comment: I tried to do so by Setting up VSCode Remote over SSH to be able to write the web pages but when I run the server it gives me the local server link which will not work

Comment: I don't talk about ssh but about two separated services. Google colab could run calculations with some Web API (Django-REST, Fast API) which can get data from external computer/user, and runs calculations, and sends result as response from API. And your local computer could runs Django web server which use i.e.e `requests` to send information to Google using its Web API, and get result.

Comment: did you run Django on Google server? Did check how you generate links? Maybe you had hardcoded `http://localhost`. VScode can be used to edit code but you have to start it from Google colab.